# UINavigationController Popping View With Child

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UINavigationController in which I have to add a view controller to a view controller like so:

`[self.navigationController addChildViewController:vc];`

Because of this, when tapping the back button automatically generated for by my nab controller, it pops back to the main view, however it doesn't remove the child view controller I added.

How can I check to remove or pop the child view controller at the same time at which the parent view controller pops?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol has a method:

```
 - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
       willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
                     animated:(BOOL)animated
```

that is called whenever the nav controller changes a view controller.  Implement this method, and do your logic there.

Comment: No luck. From root view to last child view I have, vcOne (root view controller), that pushes vcTwo (which holds vcThree), then of course vcThree (which is added to vcTwo using `addChildViewController`). Upon returning to vcOne from vcTwo I need to get rid of vcThree (which stays on screen having been added to vcTwo fro some reason).

Comment: You'll need to remove the subviews yourself ( [mySubView removeFromSuperview]; )  The method I mentioned above just tells you where you are in the hierarchy, and when the hierarchy changes.

Comment: I've tried `[vcThree removeFromParentViewController];` with no luck (inside said delegate method).

Comment: @JoshKahane - sorry, all I know is what I've read in the docs.  If I come across anything, I'll post it here.